# What is the best way to show/hide special_price on frontend using custom attribute?

Tags: admin, magento-1.8, catalog, product-attribute, price

I am trying to figure out the best way implement a checkbox in Magento admin that will allow for users to select whether to display a special price on the frontend or not.

I understand that this can be set via product attributes but I would like to be able to select which products will have the special price shown or not by ticking a checkbox to "Show special price on frontend"...

So far I have created the attribute `show_special_price` I now need to add this to an IF condition within the template.

```
$_specialPriceStoreLabel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('show_special_price', '1');
```

but I can't figure out which line since there are many IF conditions in there.

Comment: why don't you have that attribute as "yes/no" select type?

Comment: @Shathish yes the attribute is yes/no option I just need to find where to add the if condition since price.phtml is 400 lines long!

Comment: simple answer would be find all occurrence of `class="special-price"` in the file and put all those markups inside your condition. But remember! there's always a better solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

instead of attribute, create a system configuration of enabled/disabled, follow below link to know how to get started.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/

and use yes/no option i.e the second one.

Comment: that's a better !dea, but the user wants to know, where to add the condition

Comment: use template path hint to check the location of phtml file for special price